# Display pivot table filter values

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I have a pivot table where I have applied a date filter:

[image]

I am looking for a way to display the filter information in a cell.

e.g. **between 1/1/2015 and 10/3/2015**

I have tried the following to just get it to display the information in a message box:

```
Sub DisplayRange()

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("OrdersPerSlot").PivotFields("PickDate").PivotFilters(1)
        MsgBox "FilterType: " & .FilterType & vbCr _
         & "Value1: " & .value1 & vbCr _
         & "Value2: " & .value2
    End With

End Sub
```

I get the following error:

[image]

Next I moved the code into the "ThisWorkBook" Object in case there was some referencing issue and got this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need VBA for this. By running the Macro Recorder while adding a date filter I came up with:

```
Sub GetPivotFilterDates()
Dim pvt As Excel.PivotTable
Dim pvtField As Excel.PivotField

Set pvt = Worksheets(1).PivotTables(1)
Set pvtField = pvt.PivotFields("Date Range")
With pvtField.PivotFilters(1)
    If .FilterType = xlDateBetween Then
        Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "Filter is between " & .Value1 & " and " & .Value2
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I like your thinking. Will give it a go in the morning and report back.

Comment: Hi, I could not get your suggestion to work. I carried on researching based on what you posted, simply looking for a way to get the filter values but the suggestion came up with the same type of error. See update to original post for details...

Comment: The code you added works for me. I can get it to error by messing up the pivot table name or field name or removing the filter, but the error is "Subscript out of range."

Comment: Strange. Where is you place the code and how did you execute it?

Comment: It's in a module in Personal.xlb, where I run stuff I'm fooling around with. Where is yours? Not that it should matter - this is pretty straightforward code.

Comment: Sussed it. For some reason the macro recorded the name "PickDate" for the field when the field is actually called "Date Range" The code now shows a message box with the values. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, I wondered why you changed the field name :). Glad it's working!

Comment: just an FYI for anyone who comes across this. use the following if statement before looking at the filter values to check if the filters have been cleared:  If Worksheets("OrdersPerSlot").PivotTables("OrdersPerSlot").PivotFields("Date Range").PivotFilters.Count > 0 Then...  This will prevent a 'Subscript out of range' error